# How can I allow a user to send from an address belonging to a distribution group?

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a distribution group that has the address `sales@contoso.com` associated with it. I now want a member of that group to be able to *send* emails using that email address.

I added the address in Outlook, but when I send an email, Exchange complains that the user is not authorized to use the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're going to want to assign **Send-As** permissions to the user. This can either be done through PowerShell or MMC.

#### 1a) Assign Send-As Permissions through PowerShell

Enter the following command into PowerShell on the Exchange server.

```
Add-ADPermission -Identity "CONTOSO Sales" -User "CONTOSO\UserName" -ExtendedRights Send-As
```

#### 1b) Assign Send-As Permissions through MMC

You can manually [assign **Send-As** permissions for the distribution group to the user](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2005/01/07/assigning-send-as-permissions-to-a-user/) through MMC.

1. On an Exchange computer, click **Start**, point to **Programs**, point to **Microsoft Exchange**, and then click **Active Directory Users and Computers**.
2. On the **View** menu, click to select **Advanced Features**.
3. Expand **Users**, right-click the *MailboxOwner* object where you want to grant the permission, and then click **Properties**.
4. Click the **Security** tab, and then click **Advanced**.
5. In the **Access Control Settings for *MailboxOwner*** dialog box, click **Add**.
6. In the **Select User, Computer, or Group** dialog box, click the user account or the group that you want to grant "Send as" permissions to, and then click **OK**.
7. In the **Permission Entry for *MailboxOwner*** dialog box, click This Object Only in the **Apply** onto list.
8. In the **Permissions** list, locate **Send As**, and then click to select the **Allow** check box.
9. Click **OK** three times to close the dialog boxes.

[Several online sources](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2961-how-to-send-as-from-a-distribution-group-with-exchange-2010) note that it is important that **only** the **Send-As** permission is assigned to the user. I have not verified this, but it is worth trying.

Apparently, changing this setting might not have any effect immediately. [It has been noted](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/72b54918-3216-47fe-9edb-dce3ccc0bbf1/send-on-behalf-send-as-a-distribution-list?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy) that restarting the Exchange Information Storage Service will cause it to be effective right away.

#### 2) Grant SendOnBehalf Permissions to the User

If the Send-As permissions does not yield the desired result, you may want to try assigning the SendOnBehalf permission for the group to the user:

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity "CONTOSO Sales" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo "CONTOSO\UserName"
```